# Method not found while calling My Google Business API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-business-profile-api, google-business-profile

I am facing below error while fetching localposts from My google Business API

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 404,
        "message": "Method not found.",
        "status": "NOT_FOUND"
    }
}
```

I have enabled My google Business API already.

[Available quota](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wKiG.png)

Comment: Do you have quota?

Comment: Are you using GET https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/{parent=accounts/*/locations/*}/localPosts?

Comment: Yes I have qouta @vpgcloud and yes i am using the mentioned API. Please help I need to fix it on urgent basis

Comment: Can you verify that the location exists and has local posts?

Comment: Yes, I have verified that the location has localPosts

Comment: Have you tried it via the OAuth playground? I'm thinking the 404 could be masking an authorisation error, e.g. you're using the wrong credentials.

Comment: OAuth playground gives me error of URI mismatch, and I am able to generate access token from postman and using the same token for API calling as well, so I don't think so there would be an authorisation error.

Comment: Can you get reviews and media?

Comment: No, while calling review API, I am getting the same error.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of your quotas dashboard filtered to the Google My Business API? https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas

Comment: I have added the screenshot of available qouta. Please find it in the post

Comment: Are you using a client library? If so, which one? If not, what discovery link are you using?

Comment: Actually, I am integrating it with salesforce and I am not using any discovery link. If it is required, can you please help me with it?

Comment: I would highly recommend a client library or using the discovery link, see documentation here: https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest
What programming language are you using?

Comment: I can't use client library as I am using apex language. I am doing custom integration with salesforce.

Comment: In that case, please post the apex code you have to far.

Answer (score 0):

Use this discovery document link https://developers.google.com/static/my-business/samples/mybusiness_google_rest_v4p9.json